# Memory management when updating the items in a NSMenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmenu

I'd like to know if this is the correct way to avoid a memory leak in a Cocoa app.

My app has a method that updates an `NSMenu`'s items:

```
//Remove and Release old Status Scan Menu:
if ([statusMenuScansMenu numberOfItems] !=0) {
    for (NSMenuItem *menueItemToBeReleased in [statusMenuScansMenu itemArray]) {
        [statusMenuScansMenu removeItem:menueItemToBeReleased];
        [menueItemToBeReleased release];
    }
}

//New Status Scan Menu:
for (MyObject* myObject in myArray) {
    NSMenuItem * scanMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
    [scanMenuItem setTitle:[myObject name]];
    [statusMenuScansMenu addItem:scanMenuItem];
}
```

As you can see, before adding new items I remove all previous items and send `release` to them. Then I add the new ones.

Is this the best way for memory management?

If I analyze my code in Xcode 4.1, it says that there is a *potential* memory leak.

Comment: Where does it say the potential memory leak is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like how you are doing it should *probably* work OK, but it is kind of an odd way to go about it.

If you can require OS X 10.6+, your code could be consolidated to the following:

```
//Remove old Status Scan Menu:
[statusMenuScansMenu removeAllItems];

//New Status Scan Menu:
for (MyObject* myObject in myArray) {
    NSMenuItem * scanMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] 
      initWithTitle:[myObject name] action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""] autorelease];
    [statusMenuScansMenu addItem:scanMenuItem];
}
```

Note that by adding an `autorelease` during the creation of the `NSMenuItem` in the lower loop, there is no need to send the extra `release` during the menu item removal like in your code. In some sense, an `NSMenu` acts like an `NSArray` does with the sub menus and menu items it contains: it retains them. So since you are inserting the newly created `NSMenuItem` directly into the `NSMenu`, it's as if the `NSMenu` is taking ownership of the menu item. As such, you need to counteract the +1 retain count that you get from the alloc/init creation of the item to make sure you don't get a memory leak. In your code, you were counteracting that +1 retain count by sending it an explicit/extra release during the menu item removal, which is kind of roundabout. In the above code that I posted, by adding the `autorelease` during the creating in the lower loop, the only thing "holding on to" the menu items will the the menu. Then, later, when you call the `removeAllItems` method, the menu will send a `release` to each menu item, at which point their retain count should drop to 0, and they'll be deallocated.

If you need to support versions of OS X prior to 10.6, you can use the above code, except substitute `[statusMenuScansMenu md_removeAllItems]` for `[statusMenuScansMenu removeAllItems]`. You can then create this `md_removeAllItems` method in a category on `NSMenu` like so:

```
@interface NSMenu (MDAdditions)
- (void)md_removeAllItems;
@end


@implementation NSMenu (MDAdditions)
- (void)md_removeAllItems {
    NSUInteger currentCount = [self numberOfItems];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < currentCount; i++) {
        [self removeItemAtIndex:0];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You don't need to use autorelease.  Instead, alloc/init the objects, add them to the menu, then release them.  This eliminates the need for an autorelease pool to be in place, which whilst it should always be there is sometimes something that the iPhone crowd like to avoid filling up.

Comment: @user256413: Using autorelease, especially as a habit, makes it that much harder to forget the release. On the Mac, where there's no risk (currently) that the OS will kill your process for allocating too many menu items at once, it's better to not risk leaking.